# Tailwind plugin to set styles for different breakpoints

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, tailwind-variants

There is a plugin in which the text styles are set. Is it possible to set a style for a combination of these styles at different breakpoints?

```
 /** @type {Plugin} */
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = plugin(function ({ addBase, addVariant, theme }) {
  addBase({
    '.myText-1': {
      fontWeight: '700',
      fontSize: '24px',
      lineHeight: '28px',
    },
    '.myText-2': {
      fontWeight: '400',
      fontSize: '20px',
      lineHeight: '24px',
    },
    '.typo-xx': 'myText-1 md:myText-2 lg:myText-1', //is it possible somehow?
  });
});
```

I have no idea how to do this. I assume it's possible somehow using 'addVariants'. Am I right? Or is there some other way?